# creating a rank Index

Tags: sql-server

What I am trying to achieve is to add a concatenated ranking index to my DB which can then be joined to another table.  Below is the current query to get the results.

```
select WorksOrderNumber, PartNumber, ScheduledFinishDate
 from vFM_WORKS_ORDER_HEADER 
where Complete = 'No' and ScheduledFinishDate is not null
```

I am wanting to create an index column that includes the part number `+ ' - ' + a rank number` based on the scheduledFinishedDate for that Part No. only (if that makes sense)

ie

```
WorksOrderNumber    PartNumber  ScheduledFinishDate Index
28091              100767922    12/01/2018 00:00    100767922 - 2
28300              100767922    09/10/2017 00:00    100767922 - 1 
28092              100767922    26/01/2018 00:00    100767922 - 3 
29166              T1043501     04/12/2017 00:00    T1043501 - 2 
29167              T1043501     25/01/2018 00:00    T1043501 - 3 
29168              T1043501     19/10/2017 00:00    T1043501 -1
```

Regards

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on why you are subracting `-2,-1`

Comment: How could the ranking index be joined to another table if the value hasn't yet been calculated and stored there? It seems the rank should be a separate column, formatted for display purposes in the app code.

Comment: @TheGameiswar I think they are just dashes being used as separators.

Comment: Yes the dashes are just separators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    WorksOrderNumber,
    PartNumber,
    ScheduledFinishDate,
    PartNumber + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), rn) AS [Index]
FROM
(
    SELECT WorksOrderNumber, PartNumber, ScheduledFinishDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PartNumber ORDER BY ScheduledFinishDate) rn
    FROM yourTable
)
```